# point to another structure in C

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to design a datastructure that uses singly linked list and stack operations. I get the concept of this. It is like you have a room and you are stacking/linking the person to that room. The rooms are linked too. However, I cant find some examples/reference for this, I can only find self-referential structure examples.

- Is my data structure design correct?
- How do you connect the person to the room?
- Do you know some good references/websites that teaches this?

  ```
  struct room
  {
   int roomnumber;
   struct room *link;
  };

  struct person
  {
   int personnumber;
   struct person *next;
   struct room *link;
  };
  ```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, when designing the data structures you should keep in mind the operations that you are going to do with data.

Now I see that you organize the lists of rooms and persons. And to connect persons with room you define `person.link` in such structure you are able to understand easily where the person is, but to find who is in room you will do BIG WORK (go through all people to see where they are). So think over what your program will do with rooms and persons, i.e. which operations will be the most frequent.

**EDIT:**

Perhaps possible alternative can be:

```cpp
struct room
{
 int roomnumber;
 struct room * nextRoom;
 struct person * personList;
};

struct person
{
 int personnumber;
 struct person *next;
};
```

here room has a list of people (persons) who are in it, so it will be easy to find someone (all find all people) in a particular room, but quite difficult to determine where is a person whose number is specified for the search

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I just want to push() a person/s to the room, like a stack list. Your data structure is more likely correct. What do you mean by quite difficult to determine? Do you mean it is difficult to find a specific person?

Comment: Yes. Difficult to find person by personnumber.

Answer (score 0):

> Is my data structure design correct?

You said you're "linking the person to that room", but I only see the room linked to the person.

> How do you connect the person to the room?

Add a `person` pointer to `room`.

> Do you know some good references/websites that teaches this?

[Off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Your design seems incorrect.   If the list of people is associated with a room, it would seem more natural to have a `struct person *` member of `struct room`, and no need for a `struct room *` member of `struct person`.  If you need to be able to determine a room when you are presented with a person, then it makes sense to keep the `struct room` in the `struct person`, but this is a tradeoff in your design (you are wasting a lot of memory with the redundant information, and it seems likely that anytime you are accessing a person you already know which room you are dealing with), but you have not provided enough information to make that determination.